# Поиск цикла минимальной длины во взвешенном ориентированном графе

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Дан ориентированный взвешенный граф. Требуется найти цикл, сумма весов которого должна быть минимальной, или доказать, что его не существует. Можно проходить через одну и ту же вершину по нескольку раз. Как это можно сделать наиболее оптимально? Может быть для такого случая есть какой-нибудь алгоритм?

Answer (score 2):

А кто у нас для ориентированных взвешенных графов имеется?  Да Флойд-Уоршелл же.

Используя Флойда-Уоршелла, найдём кратчайшие пути между всеми парами вершин.
Потом для каждой дуги A-B переберём остальные вершины С, смотря на сумму вес(A-B) + B->C + C->A

Comment: вот это да! вот это я понимаю!

Comment: А как затем проверить, чтобы цикл проходил через определённые вершины графа хотя бы по одному разу?

Comment: Это уже совсем другой вопрос. На исходный я ответил. Верните вопрос в первоначальное состояние.